# jQuery - call a function whenever content in Div increases/decreses

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, dom

I want to call a function whenever the content in a particular DIV changes.
For example:

I have a div. This div displays some data on page load. On another button click, there is some more data displayed in the same div. When data in the div increases, I want to call another function.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share your current code

Comment: Please search the web before asking.. this question has been already asked by another user..

Answer (score 0):

> On another button click, there is some more data displayed in the same
>   div.

On click of that button, check for the content of the DIV. If the content has increased then call your function.

```
var divContent = $("div#target").text();
$("button").click(function() {
    if(divContent !== $("div#target").text()) { // you can even check for length also
        divContent = $("div#target").text();
        // call your function here
    }
});
```